# Conditionally control which objects are returned from overpass API

Tags: overpass-api

In generic form my question is: can I conditionally control what is returned from overpass query:

`[out:json];
(
   rel[/* filter /];
   // if there are relations, stop and return them
   // if not, try to find ways and then relations that include them
   way[/ filter */];
   rel(bw); // returns relations having these ways
);
out body;`

This is more specific example finding relation with San Jose city boundary:

`[out:json];
area(3600396501)->.county;
(
   rel(area.county)[admin_level][admin_level!=6];
   // if relation found, return it. For San Jose city boundary
   // coincide with county boundary, so it's not within area :(

   // Find ways that are part of that relation:
   way(area.county)[admin_level][admin_level!=6];
   // one way would be sufficient, but how can tell it give me first?
   rel(bw)[admin_level][admin_level!=6];
)->.all;
(
   rel.all[name="San Jose"];
   rel.all[alt_name="San Jose"];
   // in this case I do not need ways, but for some cities the 
   // boundary is just one way, without relation. Ideally if there are 
   // relations I would stop here and return only relations.

   // For cities with boundaries as ways:
   way.all[name="San Jose"];
   way.all[alt_name="San Jose"];
);
out body;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time, there's really no easy solution. You'd have to resort to `(if: ...)` trickery to achieve your goal. The good news though is, that conditional queries are already available in the development branch and will probably be made available with the next release.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please give example of skipping query steps using if: ? I am not that proficient in overpass, sorry...

Comment: If: per se does not skip a query, it just evaluates an expression. You could add such an expression which counts the number of entries found by the previous query statement and if it is larger than 0 have the whole expression evaluate to 'false'. This way the second query statement won't return any results, in case the first query statement already found something. Please check the overpass ql documentation in the evaluators section for details and examples.

Comment: Thank you! Performance detail question: if I use this subquery: way[if:count(relations) = 0][other_filters], will query optimizer evaluate if: before enumerating through ways? i.e will it help to reduce load on the server? My highest priority is is to make overpass query run fast, because it's bottleneck right now. Returning fewer objects if not as important, I can post process results myself.

Comment: Can you provide an overpass turbo shortlink including your full query? Otherwise there's no way to be more specific.

Comment: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/pLf  I tried to simplify query and put comments